# If you coat a lightbulb with (human) blood, will the light be tinted red?

Tags: realism, effects, lighting, evil-dead-2

<sup><sub>Foreword: I understand Halloween's over but I'm still enjoying the second half of my long marathon.</sub></sup>

In *Evil Dead II (1987)*, there is a gory scene where blood is splattered onto a lightbulb, and the room is consequently illuminated in a red tint, as if the light were to have a red filter.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This was achieved, no doubt, by simply throwing fake blood on a bulb in for a slow motion shot, and the second shot was just achieved by whacking on a red filter to any old studio light they had.

My question is: **how accurate/realistic is it?

Would blood (human or otherwise) not be too viscous, thick and opaque to allow for this effect to happen?

What *would* happen if you coated a lightbulb in blood?**

Comment: It would definitely tint the light.  I've never done this, but it makes sense that as long as it was opaque (i.e. not too thick) it would work to some degree. It should be no different than a blacklight or any other tinted bulb you can buy.

Comment: @JohnnyBones "as long as it was opaque it would work" Huh? *Opaque* is the ***opposite*** of *transparent*. The more opaque something is, the less translucent (the less light it passes through), so that sentence is either worded incorrectly by mistake, or you're confused about the word opaque, or I'm wrong and confused.

Comment: Correct.  If it was translucent, it wouldn't be red.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Ah, ok, we figured out the problem: You're confused about what translucent and opaque means. Transparent means completely see-through, like water, and you're confusing that with translucent, for some reason. Translucent means it's reflecting or absorbing some of the light, but also allows some light to pass (also known as semi-transparent), so something like a ***red filter*** is a translucent piece of glass or plastic put on top of a light/camera. Opaque means completely blocks (absorbs or reflects) all light, you cannot see behind it. So, all your comments were wrong, basically.

Comment: I'd suggest you re-read the definition of "opaque" before you go calling my comments wrong.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I laid out the definitions and differences between *transparent*, *translucent* and *opaque* in my earlier comment. If you disagree with those definitions, then it's because you are wrong and confused. Regardless, "as long as it was opaque it would work" and "If it was translucent, it wouldn't be red" are both ***completely backwards***.

Comment: "as long as it was opaque (i.e. not too thick) it would work to some degree."  Replace the word "Opaque" with it's synonym "Hazy".  Seems pretty clear to me (pardon the pun) that my answer is correct.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It's pretty tricky for me, see I'm on the side of truth, and I don't like condescending people or having to repeat that they're wrong, but I've run out of ways to say it. Honestly, you're wrong, I don't know if it takes someone else to come in and comment to tell you as well, whatever. We could agree to disagree, I'm fine with that, seeing as I know I'm correct, and you seem to be comfortably deluded into believing that you're correct so I think you'd be fine with it, too.

Comment: @JohnnyBones A sprite bottle is ***translucent***, light can pass through it and but is filtered green. A sprite can is ***opaque***, light is reflected and absorbed, totally, so you cannot see inside or through it. If you coat a lightbulb with ***opaque*** blood, by definition it means you wouldn't see any light, light does not pass through ***opaque*** objects, it only passes through ***translucent*** (red filters) and ***transparent*** materials.

Answer (score 3):

It would tint the light, but very badly, and unevenly (quite unlike the photo).

Of course, blood is a translucent liquid that will -- at first -- coat the bulb. Recall that hospitals use a gizmo that is attached to your fingertip in order to measure oxygen levels in your bloodstream. It does this, I believe, by shining light through a thin portion of your body (your fingertip) and measuring its color after passing through it. The more oxygen, the more bright red your blood will appear. (Doctors out there please correct this if I am wrong.)

But blood is also living tissue, and will die soon after leaving the body. Once it dies and is "baked" by the heat of the light bulb, its chemistry will change. It will discolor, flake, split, start to fall off the bulb, etc. After a while of some bad odor, it will probably look nothing like the photos above.

Comment: More interested in the translucency immediately post-partum (less so interested in what dried blood), so if you could elaborate some more (*you made a good point about medical equipment that relies on skin/blood translucency to function*) to give as good an accuracy/realism assessment of the *Evil Dead II*'s portrayal, you'd get my upvote

Comment: The post-partum period you are referring to would best be measured in seconds as opposed to minutes or hours. The tissue would start to die immediately when the victim dies, and deteriorate quite quickly once it's exposed to air and heat. Exposure to air would immediately start a clotting process that would change the bloods chemistry rather fast. As far as I can tell, the first sentence in my response is the best way to describe the answer to your question.

Comment: it will also probably darken after time, due to the light bulb's heat, turning into brown or black. Proof can be seen in blood sausage.